# SQL Query to partition aggregate data from Amazon AMS

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Big Query to store data from amazon ams. Each day a csv file is loaded into the database that contains the lifetime spend, clicks and impressions.  The data looks something like this:

```
date_uploaded,campaign,spend,impressions,clicks
2017-11-01,product a,100,1000,50
2017-11-01,product b,50,500,20
2017-11-02,product a,175,1600,75
2017-11-02,product b,100,1000,50
2017-11-03,product a,250,2200,110
2017-11-03,product b,150,1500,80
```

I would like to transform this data to show the daily spend (difference between previous day) so the end result would look like this:

```
date_uploaded,campaign,spend,impressions,clicks
2017-11-02,product a,75,600,25
2017-11-02,product b,50,500,30
2017-11-03,product a,75,600,35
2017-11-03,product b,50,500,30
```

Is there a way to query BQ to partition data in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `lag`. Difference for the first row in a partition would be `null` and they can be excluded with a `where` clause filter. This assumes one row per date,campaign. If there are multiple rows, sum up the values for a given day and use `lag`.

```
select * from (
select date_uploaded,campaign,
spend-lag(spend) over(partition by campaign order by date_uploaded) as spend_diff,
impressions-lag(impressions) over(partition by campaign order by date_uploaded) as impressions_diff,
clicks-lag(clicks) over(partition by campaign order by date_uploaded) as clicks_diff
from tbl
) t
where spend_diff is not null and impressions_diff is not null and clicks_diff is not null
```